# Jquery Fullcalendar not loading events

Tags: jquery, json, fullcalendar

Here is my calendar:

http://leaguemanager.localsportswire.org/caltest.cfm

Here is the JSON URL

http://leaguemanager.localsportswire.org//json.cfm?json_type=view_timeslots&league=125&requesttimeout=99999&list_type=timeslots&calendar_slots=1&return_script=/caltest.cfm

Here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var json_url = '/json.cfm?json_type=view_timeslots&league=125&requesttimeout=99999&list_type=timeslots&calendar_slots=1&return_script=#cgi.script_name#';                        
                        if ($(window).width() < 514){
                            var mydefaultview = 'basicDay';
                        } else {
                            var mydefaultview = 'month';
                        }       
    $('##timeslots').fullCalendar({                     
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },                              
        ignoreTimezone: true,                           
        allDayDefault:false,

        events: json_url,                           
        defaultView: mydefaultview,
        windowResize: function(view) {
                if ($(window).width() < 514){
                    $('##timeslots').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'basicDay' );
                } else {
                    $('##timeslots').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'month' );
                }
        },                                          
        eventAfterAllRender: function(){
            console.log('Event Rendering Complete');                            
            if ($(window).width() < 514){
                $('.fc-header-right').hide();
            } else {
                $('.fc-header-right').show();
            }                                           
        },
        eventRender: function(event,element,view) {                                                                                                                                         
            var view_title = view.title;
            var event_title = event.start;
            var event_title2 = moment(event_title).format('MMMM YYYY');                                             
            if(event_title2 !== view_title && view.name == 'month') { return false; }
            else{
            var idname = 'event' + event.id;
            $(element).attr('id', idname).addClass('ttLT').attr('title', event.title);
            var mytitle = event.title;                                                                      
            element.qtip({
                content: event.description,
                style:{classes:'qtip-bootstrap'},
                position:{my:'bottom right',at:'top left'}
            });
            }
        },                                                                      
        eventClick: function(event) 
            {
                if (event.url) 
                    {
                        new BootstrapDialog({
                            title   :   '<h3>Manage Timeslot</h3>',
                            content :   $('<div>Loading...</div>').load(event.url),
                            buttons :   [
                                {
                                    label   :   'Cancel',
                                    onclick :   function(dialog){dialog.close();}
                                }
                            ]
                        }).open();

                        return false;
                    }
            },                                                                      


        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) $('##loading').show();
            else $('##loading').hide();
        }

    }); 
                });
```

For the life of me I can't figure out why the darn events are not loading. I'm able to get it to work on other events, but I can't see what's different about these particular events vs others.

Comment: The [response](http://leaguemanager.localsportswire.org/json.cfm?json_type=view_timeslots&league=125&requesttimeout=99999&list_type=timeslots&calendar_slots=1&return_script=/caltest.cfm&start=2014-07-27&end=2014-09-07&_=1408401342481) from `json.cfm` in your live page appears to be blank: `[]`.

Comment: Yeah, thats what did it. I didnt realize fullcalendar appended additional variables to the URL string.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt realize fullcalendar appended additional variables to the URL string.